# Ionic 4 android app freeze when resume after call function

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing and app which has feature of calling a number. When i click call button it goes to dial pad and when we cancel it by back button and resumes our app then it freezes and nothing happens wherever we touch on screen. Below code i have used on call button click.

Method 1 :

```
window.open('tel:' + this.contactNo, '_system');
```

Method 2 :

```
  this.callNumber.callNumber(this.contactNo, true)
      .then( (data) =>
      {
        console.trace("called callnumber ", data);
      })
      .catch( (error) =>
      {
        console.log('Error launching dialer',error);
      });
```

I have tried both methods but same result. Any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

so i tried to replicate the issue but don't have any success on doing so.

i followed the Ionic Call Number package, [Call number From Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number)
This were my solution.

Component

```
 async openCallModal(){
    this.callNumber.callNumber("18001010101", true)
        .then(res => console.log('Launched dialer!', res))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error launching dialer', err));
  }
```

View / HTML

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-button (click)="openCallModal()" color="primary">Call</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can we open dial pad first with number and then call ? Above code directly calls the number given

Comment: I personally did not have to open dial pad before inside ionic. But i came across something that might assist you, it is a bit old but maybe it can assist with you solution.. 
(https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-open-dial-pad-when-i-click-the-call-button/118371)